# Warning with Tomcat 8 and Glassfish Metro

Tags: java, tomcat, java-metro-framework

I am using Metro 2.3.1-b104 with Tomcat 7.0.28 and all works without an issue. However, when switching to Tomcat 8.0.3 I get the following warning on every web service call (even though they still work). I see the following warning:

```
WARNING: onComplete() failed for listener of type 

[org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncListenerWrapper]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: It is illegal to call getRequest() after complete() or any of the dispatch() methods has been called
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.getRequest(AsyncContextImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSAsyncListener$1.onComplete(WSAsyncListener.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncListenerWrapper.fireOnComplete(AsyncListenerWrapper.java:35)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.fireOnComplete(AsyncContextImpl.java:100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AsyncStateMachine.asyncPostProcess(AsyncStateMachine.java:206)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.asyncPostProcess(AbstractProcessor.java:136)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:656)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any suggestions on:

1. Is it a Tomcat or Metro ?
2. What is the underlying cause ?
3. How to fix ?

Comment: I'm having the exact same Exception with Tomcat 8.0.5 without using Metro (currently on a Vaadin application), so I guess it's related to Tomcat configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When you call start() on the AsyncContext you give it an implementation of the Runnable. Call the complete() on the AsyncContext in the finally clause inside Runnable. Foe example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
         throws ServletException, IOException{

AsyncContext aContext = request.startAsync();   

  //Provide Runnable implementation to start method
  aContext.start(() ->{

    try{

        PrintWriter out;
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);  // Emulate a 3-second process

            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) aContext.getResponse();
            out = resp.getWriter();
            out.println("Hello from Async servlet");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch( InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        aContext.complete(); // close the response obj          
    }

  });

}
```

Comment: He is referring about Web Services, your solution is more related with Web Servlets.